# How to highlight a cell based off another value, remove highlight once cell is filled in

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a conditional formula that prompts me to fill out a cell whenever an adjacent cell is not blank. I'd ideally like for the cell to not be highlighted once I fill that data in, is there a way to accomplish this?

Here's the formula
=NOT(ISBLANK($H10)) **Applies to cell $I10*

I'd like to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($H10)),ISBLANK($I10))`

Comment: Nice nice, it worked!